# jquery: reading xml document, variable not being passed out of function

Tags: jquery, xml, variables

I'm reading a gpx xml document with about 1180 trackpoints, each containing an elevation tag. I can get the length but can't pass it on to use later in an if loop which calculates the total ascent.

```
var elevs = [];
var $l = 0;
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "../gpx/27-Mar-13slow.gpx",
          dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('trkseg').each(function(){
                        $l=$(this).find("trkpt").length;
                        $(xml).find('trkpt').each(function(){
                            elevs.push(+$(this).find('ele').text());
                        });
                        $('#holder').append('<div>' + $l + '</div>');
                        //fn();
                    });
                }
      });
```

ie `$('#holder').append('<div>' + $l + '</div>');` correctly displays the total number of trackpoints, but moving it outside of the function it doesn't. What I assume to be the global variable `$l` won't change to the trackpoint length. Can anyone enlighten me as to why? (The elevs array contains the elevation data ok)

Comment: Your ajax function is asynchronous, so when trying to use the variable outside the success callback, the ajax function has'nt completed yet and your variable still contains zero. You have to wait for the ajax call to finish before you can use the data, and that's why the success callback is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the success function like this:

```
success: function (xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    var $trkseg = $xml.find("trkseg");
    $trkseg.each(function () {
        $l = $(this).find("trkpt").length;
        $(xml).find('trkpt').each(function () {
            elevs.push(+$(this).find('ele').text());
        });
        $('#holder').append('<div>' + $l + '</div>');
        //fn();
    });
}
```

Comment: A thing of beauty but no more successful at filling the variable! I'll have to learn what asynchronous means. But is it possible to delay things until the ajax function completes and the variable is filled?

Comment: Hmm can't edit that comment after 5 mins! Scrub 'is it possible to delay things' and substitute 'how do I wait for the Ajax call to finish before I can use the data?'